# Extjs 3.4 - Button Icon does not show or does not center

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, extjs

I want to fill a button with an icon I created but whatever I have tried just seems to put the icon either half cut off and way left, or it doesn't show at all. I've been trying different combinations of CSS and the icon, iconcls, cls button options.

I was following the Ext 3 buttons [example page](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/button/buttons.html) but that doesn't seem to display anything for me...

```
This code is an item inside my form panel (I try to replicate this with different buttons in the panel)
{
                    xtype: 'container',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'table',
                        columns: 2,
                        tableAttrs: {
                            cellspacing: 5
                        }
                    },                  
//                  padding: 5,
                    pack: 'center',
                    align: 'middle',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        width: 40,
//                      scale: 'medium',
                        ref: '../drawToolsBtn',
                        tooltip: 'Drawing Tools',
                        icon: 'img/draw.png',
                        iconAlign: 'top',
                        baseCls: 'x-plain',
//                      iconCls: 'drawBtn',
                        enableToggle: true,
//                      padding: 3,
                        toggleHandler: function(btn, state)
                        {
                            this.showDrawToolsWin(state);
                        },
                        scope: this
                    },{
                        xtype: 'label',
//                      columnWidth: 1, // remainder of container
                        padding: 3,
                        text: 'Click button to open Drawing Tools Menu'
                    }]
                }


CSS
--------------------
.drawBtn{
    background: url(../img/draw.png) !important;


}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Code seems to be correct. verify the path of the icon. Is there any ajax failure yous see in firebug console?

Comment: Icon gets retrieved, if I add a text: 'DRAW' to the button it display properly (icon centered in button).. If I don't have that it's like the icon is confined to the left half of the button.

Comment: Try this 
.drawBtn{
    background: url(../img/draw.png) center right no-repeat !important;
}

Comment: That doesn't show anything.. If i remove the text option, the button will be blank.

Comment: The example says background-image: url(../img/draw.png) !important;

In your code, it is just background..!!

Comment: I had background-image, but the button was blank. background at least got the image on the button...

Comment: Check my solution over here

[Ext js Custom button icon size ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609727/how-to-correctly-set-icon-size-of-a-button-in-extjs/13300483#13300483

Answer (score 0):

```
.drawBtn{
    background-image: url(../img/draw.png) !important;
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I've literally tried dozens and dozens configurations. the css works well when I have the text option set but that's about it.